# Android progressbar in image thumbnail

Tags: android, progress-bar, thumbnails

I have a gridview with an adapter that loads and caches images from the web. What I'm trying to do is find a way to have individual progress spinners for each image. I like the indeterminate ProgressBar, and I'm trying to find a way to use it without a ViewSwitcher. I used the indeterminate drawable from the progress bar...

```
row.setImageDrawable(new ProgressBar(c).getIndeterminateDrawable());
```

...but it's too big and doesn't animate. Is there a simpler way to achieve the results I'm looking for? Or is there a way to tweak my approach to get the results that I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create grid item layout with ImageView and ProgressBar shown by default. When the image loads you can make ProgressBar invisible. I have not tested this but should work.

How do you load those images from the Internet?